# How to find the remainder of a division in python?

Tags: python, math, division, equation

In python, after I have divided to variables (k and h) How do I then find the remainder of the equation? This is the code I have:

```
h = int(input())
print(k / h)
```

Comment: With the modulus operator: `k%h`. If you want both the result and the remainder `divmod(k,h)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple math does the trick:

```
h = int(input())
print(k % h)
```